# How to add controls to a VideoSurface in Famo.us

Tags: javascript, famo.us

As a developer I would like to be able to set controls on a VideoSurface in Famo.us. By adding a way to set them on a surface, one could set video controls like play(), pause() and stop().

That's more of a story...

Anyway I need a way to set video controls for a VideoSurface the right way in Famous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend the VideoSurface to bring in other properties through your options and even add your own methods (functions) to be able to control the video playback.

**Here is an example of the extended VideoSurface: [with native controls](http://jsfiddle.net/L1y5uhL5/)**

```
    var VideoSurface = require('famous/surfaces/VideoSurface');

function VideoExtraSurface(options) {
    VideoSurface.apply(this, arguments);
    this.options.controls = options && options.controls ? options.controls : false;
    this._superDeploy = VideoSurface.prototype.deploy;

}

VideoExtraSurface.prototype = Object.create(VideoSurface.prototype);
VideoExtraSurface.prototype.constructor = VideoExtraSurface;

VideoExtraSurface.prototype.deploy = function deploy(target) {
    this._superDeploy(target);
    target.controls = this.options.controls;

    this._videoElement = target;
}

module.exports = VideoExtraSurface;
```

**Here is another example: [Your own play/pause](http://jsfiddle.net/9uj07nc1/)**

```
var VideoSurface = require('famous/surfaces/VideoSurface');

function VideoExtraSurface(options) {
    VideoSurface.apply(this, arguments);
    this.options.controls = options && options.controls ? options.controls : false;
    this._superDeploy = VideoSurface.prototype.deploy;

}

VideoExtraSurface.prototype = Object.create(VideoSurface.prototype);
VideoExtraSurface.prototype.constructor = VideoExtraSurface;

VideoExtraSurface.prototype.deploy = function deploy(target) {
    this._superDeploy(target);
    target.controls = this.options.controls;

    this._videoElement = target;
}

VideoExtraSurface.prototype.play = function play() {
    return this._videoElement.play();
}

VideoExtraSurface.prototype.pause = function pause() {
    return this._videoElement.pause();
}

module.exports = VideoExtraSurface;
```